# Font is NOT resizing with rems

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

It should be simple, but for whatever reason rem isn't working for me.

For example I have

```
    <div id="big_paragraph">
        <p>I will make sure you get upvoted,</p>
        <p>if you answer this simple question</p>
        <p>for me. Thanks!</p>
    </div><!-- big_paragraph -->
```

And I want the font-size to be responsive, so in my CSS I have

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:none;
}

html{
    font-size: 62.5%;
/* I also tried font-size: 16px; to no avail */
}

body{
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}

#big_paragraph{
    margin-top:101px;
    font-size: 4.1rem;/*41px*/
    text-align:center;
}
```

I don't know if it matters but I also have the following in my head section of my html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1smvmeLt/

Comment: Looks OK on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v2x0Lv32/), can you post more of the html/whatever the text is nested under?

Comment: responsive in what way?

Comment: Can you define "isn't working for me"? This certainly appears to work, based on my expectations from reading the code.

Comment: @William - I want it to change in size as the browser window is resized.

Comment: @AlexGriffs - It resizes on fiddle for you? It doesn't for me. I have a lot of code for this project, so I'm not sure what else to mention codewise.

Comment: I do have the div inside of a <div id="wrapper">, which I haven't written any styles for.  After that I have a <div id="content"> after my header. After that I have two divs with id's of "col_1" and "col_2". <div id="big_paragraph"> is inside of col_2.

Comment: Rem is not related to screen size, so no it does not resize with the screen, sorry I was a bit unclear that you were looking for that. Add some media queries and adjust your html font-size and you will be good to go.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work but would probably only work in modern browsers.

```
.some-paragraph{
    font-size: 5vw !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to change it based on the [media query](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). So, cleaning it up a bit, this worked for me. Hope this helps.

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

#big_paragraph{
    margin-top:101px;
    font-size: 4.1rem;/*41px*/
    text-align:center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {

   #big_paragraph  { 
      font-size: 150%; 
   }

}
```

```html
    <div id="big_paragraph">
        <p>I will make sure you get upvoted,</p>
        <p>if you answer this simple question</p>
        <p>for me. Thanks!</p>
    </div><!-- big_paragraph -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working just fine for me.

I would however recommend using a class instead of an id so that you can reuse the css if needed later.

I would have made this a comment, but I do not have that ability yet.

Comment: Comments were not there when I originally posted. He could use a % or vw instead of rem to resize based on the browser size.